# count number of rows in DVWP where status = not started and author = author

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a library with @Author, @status, and @fileleafref (document).

I have the following line in the dvt_1 template in my DVWP

```
<xsl:variable name="C_Draft" select="count($Rows[normalize-space(@Status)='Draft'])" />
```

This works, but I want to return only the count for items where @status is draft "and" where @Author = Field value of @Author (thus dynamic).  So, for example, do a count where status=draft and author=john smith.  How would I do this in a situation where there are a number of authors?

EDIT
Here's what I've got based on your GetUsername template (thanks):

```
<xsl:variable name="AuthoredBy"  select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(@Author, 'ID='), '&lt;'), '&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="C_Draft" select="count($Rows[normalize-space(@Status)='Draft' and @Author = $AuthoredBy])" />
```

This returns 0, though it should show 1 for author1.  So I tried this, which also returns 0.  It does parse and return the correct Username, which I checked.

```
<xsl:variable name="C_Draft" select="count($Rows[@Author = $AuthoredBy])" />
```

Then I tried this:

```
<xsl:variable name="C_Draft" select="count($Rows[normalize-space(@Status)='Draft' and $AuthoredBy = 'Author2Name'])" />
```

This gave me a value of 1, but it is Author 1 that has 1 item in draft status, not author 2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you try domain\jsmith or whatever the domain id for the author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the additional filter clause inside the brackets with and. If both conditions are true, the row (item) will be included in the sum.

@Author is a Person or Group column, so you'll need to parse out the part of the HTML which represents the person that you need. See my XSL templates at the SPXSLT Codeplex Project (http://SPXSLT.codeplex.com).

Comment: Marc, I posted my reply but the sample code/results from your reply got added below the question.  I seem to be running into trouble with counting using the person group column as a filter.  Thanks for pointing me to your SP templates.  Parsing string worked.

Comment: This is now solved.  I was using the GetUserName template from the series of templates that Marc has made available, when I should have been using GetUserID template.

Comment: Can you mark the answer? :-)

Comment: Sorry Marc.  New to the site and my other computer wasn't showing the check mark so I assume whether or not the check mark shows is cookie based.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is do a 'Group By' in XSLT so that the counts are grouped by Author.
Although, not exactly the same thing, I believe the following solution could be modified to work for you:
[Grouping XML using XSLT](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/groupxml.aspx)